# How can I preview PSD's in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, photoshop, psd

I would like to be able to see thumbnails of my PSD's. Any ideas?

Comment: use mac. shortest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work on Windows 8

http://thecustomizewindows.com/2010/10/enable-thumbnail-view-for-psd-files/

I think is the same in Windows 7.

Comment: There are some mistakes with the registry data in that blog. I don't recommend using it, unless you are an expert and can fix it.

Comment: It does not work for Windows 7 64 bits (only 32 bits).

Answer (score 0):

The built in thumbnail viewer is very slow. I suggest to use ACDsee picture viewer for both thumbnail view and faster picture browsing.

Comment: To add more information. When progressing big PSDs and RAW files in Windows, it's very slow due to the rendering of large files. Somehow ACDsee does this as fast as viewing 1mb pictures in Windows Thumbnail Viewer.